# Three similar MySql queries, one not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am not a php programmer, but stitched three very similar queries to the same table together, the first two work, the last function get_adres is not returning any output. What is wrong PLEASE?
edit:The first two functions work fine, the last one get_adres() returns the commas.

```
function get_posit() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_ads = $wpdb->prefix."awpcp_ads";
    $adid = get_query_var('id');
    $ad_lat = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT geo_lat FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid';"));
    $ad_lon = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT geo_lon FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid';"));
    $adpos = $ad_lat.",".$ad_lon;
    return $adpos;
}

function get_titles() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_ads = $wpdb->prefix."awpcp_ads";
    $adid = get_query_var('id');
    $adtitle = 'Position '.$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ad_title FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid';"));
    return $adtitle;
}

function get_adres() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_ads = $wpdb->prefix."awpcp_ads";
    $adid = get_query_var('id');
    $street = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT adcontact_countyvillage FROM $tbl_ads WHERE   ad_id='$adid';"));
    $plz = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT adcontact_state FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid';"));
    $city = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT adcontact_city FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid';"));
    $adrs = $street.",".$plz.",".$city;
    return $adrs;
}
```

Comment: echo your queries and run in phpmyadmin see if it returns morethan one row?

Comment: Why do you have 2 or 3 SELECTs on 1 table?? Try `"SELECT geo_lat,geo_lon FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid';"` Also check this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) on using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

get_var returns a single value. for your queries on the bottom, try adding limit 1 to them, so

```
    $street = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT adcontact_countyvillage FROM $tbl_ads WHERE   ad_id='$adid' LIMIT 1;"));
    $plz = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT adcontact_state FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid' LIMIT 1;"));
    $city = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT adcontact_city FROM $tbl_ads WHERE ad_id='$adid' LIMIT 1;"));
```

Comment: Thank you, didnt help. Put a if(function exists) on the page, returns also the commas.